# What is the sample standard error formula?

Tags: distributions, self-study, statistical-significance, standard-error

What is the sample standard error formula?

I know only $s$ but I guess this is not it.

I am confused about its formula. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry - misread question.

Comment: @conjectures Why?

Comment: Standard error of what quantity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to give an answer anyway (I looked at the image and you need the sample standard error of the mean):

> The standard error is the standard deviation of the sampling
>   distribution of a statistic. Wikipedia

So
$$
SE_\bar{x}\ = \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} 
$$
and 
$$
S = \sqrt{S^2} := \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}} 
$$
So regarding the question about the CI of your image posted on mathematics:
$$
\text{Lower endpoint} =\bar X - 1.96 \times SE_{\bar{x}}= \bar X - 1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
and the upper endpoint of the 95% confidence interval is:
$$\text{Upper endpoint} = \bar X + 1.96 \times SE_{\bar{x}}=\bar X + 1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}. 
$$
and s is your estimate for $\sigma$, so you just plug in s for $\sigma$.

But in your question the standard error is already given, so you just have to calculate the CI in the following way:
$$
\text{Lower endpoint} =10 - 1.96 \times 16
$$
and the upper endpoint of the 95% confidence interval is:
$$
\text{Upper endpoint} = 10  + 1.96 \times 16. 
$$

Comment: Using 1.96 as the multiplier here is a little optimistic, even though the question elsewhere does specify 95% confidence interval. The multiplier should be based on a t distribution. Perhaps that's a fine point, and OP may not have been taught that, but in this and other respects the question is poorly posed.

Comment: @NickCox in the picture posted by him it says 95% and it seems, that this is a beginner question, so I think they use the normal distribution and not the t distribution?

Comment: Thanks for soltion. I understand what I need to write when said sample standard error:)